# Find the number of points necessary to interpolate $\cos(x)$ linearly with an absolute error that is $< 5*10^{-7}$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, error-function, numerical-calculus

> It is necessary to build a table of values for the function $f(x) =
>  \cos(x)$ such that the linear interpolation for every value $x \in
>  [0,\pi]$ has an absolute error that is inferior to $5\cdot 10^{-7}$.
> **Knowing that the values on the table are equally spaced and rounded to
> 3 decimal places**, what should be the least number of entries on the
> table?

If it wasn't for the bolded part I'd just do

$$\frac{(x_1-x_0)^2}{8}\max_{[x_0,x_1]}{|f''(x)|} < 5\cdot 10^{-7}$$

And solve for h, where $h = x_1-x_0$, and then do $\pi/h$. The problem is that rounding error. How do I add it to this?

Comment: How can you hope to get data that is correct to 7 places if the table values only have 3 places? Or is it meant that the $x$ values get rounded to 3 places and the function values remain at 7 places? @Moo, as usual in reading a table, it is meant to be linear interpolation between table values, in total a piecewise linear interpolation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann No idea. This is my prof's exercise.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm going to ask another professor about this and see what he thinks. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @LutzLehmann "Or is it meant that the x values get rounded to 3 places and the function values remain at 7 places?" I guess? Does that even make sense?

Comment: Not really, as the most natural distance from the error bound is actually $10^{-3}$ (perhaps $2·10^{-3}$) and an arithmetic sequence from $0$ with that distance will all have only 3 digits after the decimal dot. So the remark makes no sense.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This question came up in an exam and say I wanted to bring this up to my professor, in a way that I could get him to cancel the question and give everyone the full mark on that question. What would I have to say to him?

Comment: "equally spaced" and at the same time "rounded to 3 decimal places" means that for numbers smaller 1 the distance between them is a multiple of $0.001$. However, you get a problem for numbers larger than 1, as the distance there increases to multiples of $0.01$ if only 3 digits are allowed in the number representation. ... In a written exam I would suggest to just justify that the increment $0.002$ satisfies the error bound and worry not further about the 3 digit constraint. In an oral exam one could discuss the impossibility of the task as stated.

Comment: @LutzLehmann He just replied. Yes there was an error. He gave the full mark to everyone.